# Installing ubuntu on NVIDIA graphic laptop

Tags: nvidia, laptop, nouveau, nomodeset

I wanna ask you guys how to install ubuntu on Nvidia laptop. Heres my laptop spec:

> Processor : Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ Processor 
>   Graphics : NVidia GeForce
>   GTX 950M 2GB DDR5 Windows installed

Currently, I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but the screen always got stuck on the purple screen. Then I got to hold on information that adding nomodeset on Linux line will solve the problem well the purple screen problem was resolved but it got stuck at selecting where to install ubuntu.

Then I got hold again on information by adding nouveau.modeset=0 in Linux line will resolve the problem. Well, now it's stuck on selecting what do I want to install. In desperation, I got to hold that adding modprobe.blacklist=nouveau will resolve the problem but Nah, it does not resolve anything too.

In desperation (again) I tried all combinations of those 3 flags yet it still didn't install Ubuntu. Please help me if there is any other way to install ubuntu. Some suggest me to use the virtual box but I don't want it.

Comment: "Well now it stuck on selecting what do I want to install."

What do you mean by that?

Comment: your usb key needs to be created with rufus, you need to select GPT and UEFI bios mode in rufus and when you try to boot to it select the UEFI or EFI choice for your usb key.